# Reorder JSON with new key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a large JSON returned from a rest service and I need to sort it before I can use it.

Example lines:

```
[{"Time":"1354233600000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0"},
{"Time":"1354234500000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.0020288255172466159"},
{"Time":"1354235400000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.0022446943714048121"},
{"Time":"1354236300000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.00014998416164500384"},
{"Time":"1354237200000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0"},
{"Time":"1354238100000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.00015631034628383933"},
{"Time":"1354239000000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"1.1165024734559951E-05"}
```

There are about 2000 lines like this. I would like to sort them by time and get something like this:

```
var restData = { "1354234500000":[
                                  {"Name":"NaN",
                                   "TagValue":"0",
                                   "TagValue2":"someFloat"}
                                   {"Name:"NAN,
                                    "TagValue":"0",
                                     "TagVale":"0"}
                                   ],
                   "aNewUnixTimeStamp":[
                                     {..........}
]};
```

Is there some magic javascript function that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: The one you're about to write could be pretty magical.

Comment: Been asked and answered plenty of times, for example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: Looks like you're trying to sort by the key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: @gview this is not about ordering, this is more liking grouping objects by a property.

Comment: This question isn't clear to me. Are you saying you just want to restructure the data? Or restructure and sort? Could you show a larger sample of the before and after to give a better idea?

Comment: Is this possible? to reorder by timeStamp and the rest as nested object?

Comment: Yes, but with `aNewUnixTimeStamp`, are we creating a new timestamp, or using the existing ones? And how does the sorting work? Is it a simple ascending order?

Comment: Yes using the timestamp in the rows as the key for the rest of the object there are about 96 different timestamp in the rest call.

Comment: And the sorting would be one timestamp has many objects - a one to many relation.

Comment: I see, so you need matching timestamps to have their objects grouped together. Right?

Comment: Yes, thank you, as you probably guessed English is not my native language :) But yes you nailed it, is that possible?

Comment: I posted an answer that should take care of it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myarray = [{"Time":"1354233600000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0"},
{"Time":"1354234500000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.0020288255172466159"},
{"Time":"1354235400000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.0022446943714048121"},
{"Time":"1354236300000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.00014998416164500384"},
{"Time":"1354237200000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0"},
{"Time":"1354238100000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"0.00015631034628383933"},
{"Time":"1354239000000","Name":"NAN","TagValue":"0","TagValue2":"1.1165024734559951E-05"}
```

---

```
var result = myarray.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (res.hasOwnProperty(obj.Time) === false) {
        res[obj.Time] = [];
    }
    res[obj.Time].push(obj);
    delete obj.Time;
    return res;
}, {});
```

You should be aware that since the result is using the timestamps as keys of an object you won't be able to sort them since objects have no defined order.

Also `.reduce()` will need a shim for older browsers. You can use the one [provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Compatibility).

Comment: What is `delete obj.Time` for in this?  Otherwise it's straightforward.... Nevermind.  I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your objects are all neatly organised in an array, you can just call

```
bigArray.sort(function(a,b) {return a.Time < b.Time ? -1 : 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this pligin from jquery

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/sort

```
$(dataSet).sort("Time", "asc");
```

Comment: -1 because it would be lunacy to load a large DOM manipulation library *(and plugins)* just to do simple object manipulation.

Comment: @user1689607 There are about 2000 lines of data hmmmm may be simple object manipulation but with huge data plus why not use something that there to do a job for you

Comment: Loading jQuery won't make any of those 2000 lines disappear. Using generalized abstractions just slows things down.

Comment: why unless you write your own sorting you still use designed function do not see any point of what you want to prove

Comment: Code written for a specific task will generally outperform code written to handle a larger range of generalized tasks. Anyway the performance is secondary. It makes no sense to load a large DOM manipulation library just to do a simple sort. You wanted to know the reason for the vote, and I've explained it in detail. If you can't understand at this point, I can't help you.